# Rendering form errors in the current view in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, render

I have an MainPagesController index page that is rendering the 'new' page from QuotesController that has a form. How do I render the MainPagesController index page with the errors of the form?

**MainPages/index**

```
<h1>Welcome to Book Quotes</h1>
<p>
  Post your favourite quotes from your favourite books
  <%= render 'quotes/new' %>
</p>
<%= render 'quotes/all_quotes' %>
```

**Quotes/new**

```
<h1>Add a quote</h1>
<%= render 'quotes/form' %>
```

**Quotes/_form**

```
<%= form_for @quote do |f| %>
  <% if @quote.errors.any? %>
    <ul>
    <% @quote.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :passage %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :passage %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :book_title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :book_title %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :book_author %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :book_author %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

**QuotesController**

```
def create
  @quote = Quote.new(quote_params)
  if @quote.save
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render #not sure what goes here
  end
end
```

Comment: Try giving `render :new` and see is it works.

Comment: render :new rendered the quotescontroller new view with the form error, but doesn't keep me in the same page where the form is. I want to stay in the MainPagesController index view, but display the form with its error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the form that you're dealing with is a nested form, the standard advice of `render :new` won't help you here. Instead, you could redirect the user back to the index page, passing the errors via the flash, and update your view to handle displaying those errors.

*(Just a thought: it might be worth looking into making this action powered by AJAX. The user experience might be nicer, and it simplifies your code design.)*

Anyway, in your QuotesController, the `#create` action needs to note the errors and pass them along as it redirects the user back to where they came from:

```
def create
  @quote = Quote.new(quote_params)
  if @quote.save
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    flash[:quote_errors] = @quote.errors.full_messages
    redirect_to :back # or main_pages_path
  end
end
```

Then, your Quotes/_form view needs to handle those errors:

```
<%= form_for @quote do |f| %>
  <% if flash[:quote_errors] %>
    <ul>
    <% flash[:quote_errors].each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
  # ...
```

Now, this is a bit ugly. You might be wondering -- couldn't we just pass the `@quote` object back via the flash, so the view doesn't have to change? But while that's technically possible, serializing objects into session is a dangerous path to take. I'd suggest avoiding it.

One other option would be to make the quote submission an action not on QuotesController, but on your MainPages controller. E.g.,

```
class MainPagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # ...
  end

  def create_quote
    @quote = Quote.new(quote_params) # need to move quote_params in, too
    if @quote.save
      redirect_to root_url
    else      
      render :index
    end
  end
  # ...
```

This allows the `@quote` instance variable to be accessible from your form, so the error handling as-is will work just fine. It's not very RESTful, but then again, neither are most front-end website flows.

Comment: I haven't thought of implementing it this way. Thanks Robert! I've gone with using the flash way and it's working perfectly.